Type value in sitecore 9.x for Item "{61370693-189D-44A0-ABC5-2592DBD579ED}"
What is Type value (please see the attached image from Sitecore 10.0.1) in Sitecore 9.x for Item {61370693-189D-44A0-ABC5-2592DBD579ED} (path :/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Visitor/Global Visit No).

Sc 10.0.1 , Many exceptions in log file.
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.PredicateDescriptorException
Message: No known predicate type could be determined from ' Sitecore.Analytics.Rules.Conditions.ContactVisitIndexCondition,Sitecore.Analytics' specified in the definition item (Id = '61370693-189d-44a0-abc5-2592dbd579ed', db = 'master') : Could not load type 'Sitecore.Analytics.Rules.Conditions.ContactVisitIndexCondition' from assembly 'Sitecore.Analytics'.
Source: Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.xMgmt
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.ContentTreePredicateDescriptorLocator.GetDescriptor(Guid id)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.ConditionXmlNodeConverter.LookupType(Guid descriptorId)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.ConditionXmlNodeConverter.ConvertNodeInternal(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement element)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.BaseXmlRuleNodeConverter`1.Convert(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement node)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.AndXmlNodeConverter.ConvertNodeInternal(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement element)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.BaseXmlRuleNodeConverter`1.Convert(INodeConversionContext`2 context, XElement node)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.TreeConverter.TreeConverter`2.Convert(TFromNode treeRoot)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Segmentation.RuleXmlConverter.RuleXmlConverter.CreateRule(XElement ruleElement)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.RulesBuilder.BuildXmlRules(String rulesXml)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.RulesBuilder.BuildRules(String rulesXml)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Rules.RulesValidator.ValidateRule(Interaction interaction, String rulesXml, ConditionParameters parameters)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Construction.TreeBuilder.IsApplicable(Interaction interaction, String rulesXml, ConditionParameters conditionParameters)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Construction.TreeBuilder.Build(Interaction interaction)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.AggregationContextCollector.Collect(Interaction interaction)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.TreeAggregator.Aggregate(ItemBatch`1 batch)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()


In Sitecore 9.3 (where I tested), the type value is same as that you had found in 10.0.1

Try the following steps

Clear down ALL tables in the refdata-db SQL Database.
Deploy Marketing Definitions
Restart CD, CM, Rep & PRC App Services

Hope this helps !!!
